# Build Java Project with UTF-8 on Gitlab

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8, gitlab, pipeline

I have a maven project consisting of two modules. The project locally compiles correctly.
Now I've ported this project to gitlab, but I can't get it to compile. There are a number of errors like:

```
exampleclass.java: Balcone115,42] unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
```

In the **maven-compiler-plugin** of the pom **UTF-8** encoding has been specified, and the JDK 1.7
For development I use Eclipse, with **Cp1252** encoding (default).
But what is the best practice for java projects? do you always have to set UTF-8 on Eclipse?
How can I manage to compile on gitlab?

Thank you

Comment: What about not using special characters in source files? However, you could share the project with editor setzings for eclipse (UTF-8 as default).

Comment: the project is very old (2000'). Do you recommend that I change all the special characters by hand?

Comment: You could use a script. I would set the encoding to UTF-8 in eclipse but that is just my personal opinion.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking of creating a script that would convert all my .java files to UTF-8. I think it's the only solution

Answer (score 0):

It's well into the 21st century.  Unicode is 30 years old.  Use Unicode.

Comment: I converted all .java with a script to UTF-8. In this way I solved the "unmappable character for encoding UTF-8" problems. I had no other alternative